# 1, 5, 9, 13, 17, 21,...

Tags: sequences-and-series

How would you describe the set $\{1, 5, 9, 13, 17, 21,\dots\}$ in the style of $x:P(x)=$? I know that the sequence is "the last number + 4" or $4n-3$.

Answer (score 42):

$\{n \in \mathbb N\; :\; n \equiv 1 \mod 4\}$

Comment: How do you distinguish between (n≡1) mod 4 and n≡(1 mod 4) ?

Comment: If you're going to put in parentheses at all, it should be $n \equiv 1 \ (\text{mod}\;  4)$.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Congruence_relation

Comment: (1 mod 4) is valid. (7 mod 4) + 3 = 6.

Comment: @Joshua You're confusing modular congruence with the binary modulus operation.  The usage above is designating modular congruence.

Comment: @Joshua The correct way to write it using the binary modulus operation is $(n\bmod 4)=(1\bmod 4)$, or, since $1\bmod 4=1$, $(n\bmod 4)=1$.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro "Correct" here is a very vague and difficult notion. Once you state clearly at the beginnin, that you work in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ a lot, you can safely use $k\equiv 4\operatorname{mod} n$ and everybody knows what you mean.

Comment: @yo' I'm by no means asserting that it would be incorrect to write it using modular equivalence; indeed in this case I'd probably prefer it. However, for any statement using modular equivalence there is an equivalent statement using the modulo operator and vice versa, and I was merely detailing how you would write it the other way.

Answer (score 30):

$\{4k-3 \mid k \in \mathbb{N} \}$ or $\{4k+1 \mid k \in \mathbb{N} \}$, depending on whether you consider $0$ a natural number.

Comment: I think of the options presented so far, this is the nicest in that: (i) it doesn't require an understanding of modular arithmetic; (ii) it avoids confusion with quantifiers; and (iii) it most clearly captures the *sequence* via the mapping $\{1\to 1, 2\to 5, 3\to 9,\dotsc\}$.

Answer (score 17):

$$\{n \;  \mid \; \exists k \in \mathbb N: n =4k-3\}$$

Comment: Couldn't the quantifier be the universal quantifier instead of the existential one? Isn't the thing true for all natural numbers k (excluding 0)?

Comment: No. Try to find such $k$ for $n=2$, please. Also, if I write $\forall k \in \mathbb N : n=4k-3$, and n is in this set, then we have n=4*1-3=4*2-3=4*3-3=4*4-3=.... which is clearly not true for any $n$.

Comment: But why should n ever equal 2? I need to describe the set 1, 5, 9,... , there's no 2 in there anywhere.

Comment: I meant that there is clearly(?) no natural $k$ for $n=2$: $k=1$ gives $n=1$, $k\geq2$ gives $n\geq5$.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't quite get it. If it were for all natural numbers k, wouldn't that be just 4x1-3=1, 4x2-3=5, 4x3-3=9,... and that would give all the numbers of the set?

Comment: Yes. That is your set right?

Comment: Yes it is. I'm just wondering why it couldn't be the universal quantifier. Then every natural number k would give the next member of the set, starting from 1.

Comment: It is the set of all $n$ such that there exists a natural $k$ such that $n=4k-3$. So 1 is in the set because we can take $k=1$. 2,3,4, are not in the set because we can't find such $k$. 5 is in the set because we can take $k=2$.

Comment: Secondly,  if I write $\forall k \in \mathbb N : n=4k-3$, then I am searching for $n$ that statistify $n=4k-3$ for ALL natural $k$. So we have $n=4\cdot1-3=1$ because it must hold for $k=1$.  We also have $n=4\cdot2-3=5$ because it must hold for $k=2$.  So there can't be such n.

Comment: Oh now I get it! I was thinking about it all backwards. Thank you so much!

Comment: Why not flip it around? $\{n | n=4k-3 \; \forall k \in \mathbb{N}\}$. I think this is more straightforward. Or a little more simply, $\{n | n=4k-3, \; k \in \mathbb{N}\}$.

Comment: @El'endiaStarman In that route, it'd be even easier to say $\{4n-3 \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}$

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor: That's the best.

Comment: @El'endiaStarman I didn't see it before my comment, but Morgan Rodgers posted it as [an answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1416350/72995), too.

Answer (score 3):

An arithmetic progression with first term 1 and common difference 4

(No I haven't described it in the form of $P(x)$, but this is how I would describe this number sequence...)

Answer (score 3):

It's not *exactly* the form you're looking for, but close:
$$
\{n\in\mathbb N \text{ [or }\mathbb R \text{ or whatever relevant]}: (n-1)/4 \in \mathbb N\}
$$
If you really need an equality, then you might write
$$
\{n\in\mathbb N: \mathbf1 _{\mathbb{N}} (n-1)/4 = 1\}
$$
where $\mathbf1 _{\mathbb{N}}$ is the [indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) of the set $\mathbb N$.

Answer (score 3):

You can be as simple as this, given you don't insist on the $\{:\}$ set declaration:

$$4\mathbb{N}-3 = \{1,5,9,13,17,\dotsc\}$$

if $0\notin\mathbb{N}$ by your convention; and

$$4\mathbb{N}+1 = \{1,5,9,13,17,\dotsc\}$$

if $0\in\mathbb{N}$ by your convention.

Answer (score 3):

You can represent your set as the Range set of a Function from $\Bbb N$ to $\Bbb N$ itself defined as:

$$f(x)=4x+1$$

Comment: The [codomain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codomain) of a function $\Bbb N\to\Bbb N$ is always $\Bbb N$. The notion you mean is called image or (sometimes) range. Please don't use the term "codomain" which is specifically meant to be something different, namely the set $Y$ for a function that was specified as being $X\to Y$, regardless of the actual values the function takes.

Comment: Yeah sry for the ambiguity, now it should be clearer @MarcvanLeeuwen

Answer (score 3):

$\{n\in\mathbb N:\frac{n+3}4\in\mathbb N\}$